# Does embed tag work in Vuejs template for pdfs?

Tags: vue.js, pdf, vuejs2, embed

I want to create an API to render a local pdf file with Vuejs. My solution was to embed it in an Html in public folder and then call that Html file from my component. (The pdf was also in public folder.) And this system works perfectly since I don't have any specific expectations on how the pdf opens as long as it opens. I pasted below the code.

Here is my working code;

in Public/myHtml:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <embed src="pdfs/AVV.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="1000px" />
  </div>
</body>
```

and my related component in Vue:

```
   <template>
     <a target="_blank" :href="`${publicPath}${filename}.html`">
       {{ hyperlink }}
     </a>
   </template>

   <script>
    export default {
      name: 'myComponent',
      data() {
        return { publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL }
    },
    props: {
      filename: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      },
      hyperlink: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that I was told not to use public folder and do the same through Vue views/components. But as soon as I implement the same logic within my src folder as below, it doesn't work.

Here you are the new code in my View/Component before any extraction, which is in the right direction but not any close to be working:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <embed
      src="./data/pdf/myFile.pdf"
      type="application/pdf"
      width="100%"
      height="1000px"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

I have also tried several Npm libraries for pdf-rendering in Vue. No success so far! Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem is not the embed tag. I could embed pdf files in a vue template when I put the pdf files back in a public folder. It seems like Vue cannot find them when they are in an src folder. Is that correct?